# Create vector based on range of values

Tags: matlab, range, categorical-data, bins

I would like to create a vector that contains values based on a value range in an other vector.

Example:

I have a vector

```
A = [-2 1 3 -1 5 6]
```

And would like to a vector of say 3 groups based on the value of the of vector A. Let the groups be

- Group 1: Values in A <1
- Group 2: Values in A <5 and >=1
- Group 3: Values in A >=5

The results vector would then be

```
X = [1 2 2 1 3 3]
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm sure the answer is out there, but I am missing the right search terms.

Comment: I got confused about the result `X`, what's the relationship between `X` and these 3 groups?  if you want to get values in A which are <1, you can write `A(A<1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of logical indexing:

```
A = [-2 1 3 -1 5 6]

X = 2*(A<5) + 3*(A>=5);
X(A<1)=1;
```

or assuming that you meant Group 2: <5 AND >=1

```
X = (A<1) + 2*(A>=1 & A<5) + 3*(A>=5);
```

Comment: I corrected my question so that group 2 contains values between 1 and 5. So your assumption was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Though I personally prefer logical indexing, you can also use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html). It may be overkill for this specific situation but it allows you to leverage built-in binning algorithms:

```
A = [-2 1 3 -1 5 6];
edges = [-inf 1 5 inf];

[~, ~, binidx] = histcounts(A, edges);
```

Which returns:

```
binidx =

     1     2     2     1     3     3
```

To set your bin edges you can utilize the `edges` input, per the documentation:

> Bin edges, specified as a vector. edges(1) is the left edge of the
>   first bin, and edges(end) is the right edge of the last bin.

If you don't need to leverage any of the binning algorithms, you could also use [discretize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html):

```
A = [-2 1 3 -1 5 6];
edges = [-inf 1 5 inf];
binidx2 = discretize(A, edges);
```

Which returns the same as above.

Comment: This is also very useful. I have a look at his to.